# Nonlinear Filter for image processing - looking for minimum inside a mask

Tags: matlab, for-loop, image-processing

I have an idea about a filter for images but I do not know how I can realize this without using a double-for-loop in MATLAB.

I have an image, and I want to use a linear filter mask on it, let's say:

```
[1,1,1,1,1]
```

This filter mask is moving over the image, pixel by pixel. For each neighbourhood, the pixel I is set to the **minimum** of the surrounding neighbourhood.

Here is an example:

```
[ … image data      …]
[ …                 …]
[ …                 …]
[ … 23 68 155 20 53 …]
[ …                 …]
```

For my example, I want to filter the centering pixel with the value 155. The result would be:

```
[ … image data      …]
[ …                 …]
[ …                 …]
[ … 23 68 20  20 53 …]
[ …                 …]
```

The pixel 155 gets replaced with the minimum value in his neighbourhood.

I can do this with a double-for-loop, but it is really slow, too slow to use it for my application.

Would be happy for a good idea how to increase the speed! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your filter idea is called **erosion**. It is implemented in the Image Processing Toolbox in the function [`imerode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html). In your case, you'd apply:

```
result = imerode(image_data, [1,1,1,1,1]);
```

The neighborhood can have any shape. Set elements to 0 to exclude them from the neighborhood. For example, for a roundish neighborhood you can use

```
[0,1,1,1,0
 1,1,1,1,1
 1,1,1,1,1
 1,1,1,1,1
 0,1,1,1,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is finding a moving minimum value with a specified window width along a specific row. This can be done with `movmin` function which was introduced in version 2016a.

Knowing that `movmin` processes columns by default (as dim = 1). So in your case, you may want to set the dim argument to 2 (move along the rows) and discard the endpoints for the value outside of the window. A sample code may look like:

```
k = randi(20,20,11); % make some samples
ci = 6; % sample at the center row
wd = 5; % filter window width
k(:,ci) = movmin(k(:,(ci-2:ci+2)),wd,2,'Endpoints','discard') % replace the center row samples
```

Take a look at the [movmin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmin.html) documentation to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on an own solution, when the [answer of Y. Chang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55281106/11089932) came up... I wanted to post it nevertheless. At least, the result is the same, so it seems to work.

```matlab
% Test input.
A = round(rand(5) * 10)

% Dimensions.
nRows = size(A, 1);
nCols = size(A, 2);

% Kernel.
b = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

% Step size.
step = floor(numel(b) / 2);

% Output.
B = zeros(nRows, nCols);
for k = 1:nRows
  temp = repmat(A(k, :), nCols + 2 * step, 1);
  idx = double(triu(ones(size(temp)), -numel(b) + 1) & tril(ones(size(temp)), 0));
  idx(idx == 0) = NaN;
  temp = temp .* idx;
  temp = min(temp, [], 2).';
  B(k, :) = temp(step+1:end-step);
end
B

% Compare with movmin function.
BB = movmin(A, numel(b), 2)
```

Output:

```matlab
A =
    9    2    1    6    7
    2    5    9    1    7
    2    8    5   10    4
    2    0    6    5    8
    8    3   10    7    6

b =
   1   1   1   1   1

B =
   1   1   1   1   1
   2   1   1   1   1
   2   2   2   4   4
   0   0   0   0   5
   3   3   3   3   6

BB =
   1   1   1   1   1
   2   1   1   1   1
   2   2   2   4   4
   0   0   0   0   5
   3   3   3   3   6
```